# Can I move Geany's Sidebar to the Right Side?

Tags: geany

This isn't really that important, but is there a way to change the Geany IDE's sidebar to the right side instead of the left?

http://www.geany.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, but it depends on which version of Geany you are using.
[Check out this mailing list entry](http://www.mail-archive.com/geany@uvena.de/msg02209.html) and read through the discussion.

The change was committed in October 2009. Which according to the [homepage](http://www.geany.org/) means it is in version "Geany 0.18.1".

You can [get this version from here](http://www.geany.org/Download/Releases).

I personally am using 0.18, released in August 2009, so have not tested this works.

EDIT: Following the comment, I have checked the source and can confirm the code does not appear to be there to alow this functionality.

**The answer therefore is you should be able to, but you cannot.**

I asked on #geany on freenode.net about this missing functionality, but have not had a reply yet.

You may get a result if you report this as a bug.

Comment: I cannot confirm that this change has been made in 0.18.1. I see no such option in the preferences.

Comment: The new version (0.19.1) does now have this option to put the sidebar on the right hand side.